# Implementing Angular UI router lazy resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I use Angular & UI router and I need for one of my parent states's resolves to be lazy.

The reason for this is that I have a state called `authenticated` that is inherited by a whole hierarchy of child states. I need the resolve called `isAuthenticated` to be resolved lazily (i.e. each time a child of the `authenticated` state is entered).

Here is my parent `authenticated` state:

```
    .state('authenticated', {
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'root',
        views: {
            'header@': {
                controller: 'NavbarCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'app/navbar/views/navbar.view.html'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            currentMember: ['domainService', function (domainService) {
                return domainService.currentMember();
            }],
            isAuthenticated: ['$rootScope', '$q', '$cookies', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookies) {
                return ($rootScope.globals.authenticated && $cookies.globalsAuthenticated) || $q.reject({unAuthorized: true});
            }]
        }
    })
```

I want to do that so that I can redirect unauthenticated users to login page easily.

How can I have a lazy resolve using the current implementation of the UI router (`0.2.15`)?

P.S. *I had a look at [oc lazy load](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) but is appears to be aimed at loading whole modules or files...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ***stateChangeStart*** it will help you for doing the exact thing you are looking for , check this link out

http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html

Comment: Thanks very much. Just what I needed!