# Redirect to the original requested page after login using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to do is that when the user tries to go to a page (ex- a) and he is not logged in, we want to redirect him back to Login page after he login successfully he/she redirected to page(a) .

is this possible using fromState ,toState ?

help me.

thank you

Comment: Don't know if there is an official way to do it but u could bind the url to rootScope to store it untill the user is logged in and then feed it as a redirect.

Comment: you can pass parameter in the url, and redirect to that page after logging

Comment: you can use ***stateChangeStart***  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423060/implementing-angular-ui-router-lazy-resolves

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you refresh the page after the login.

If you do and your URL does not change, you can store a parameter in the URL and act on that in your `.run` function.

If you do and your URL resets, you can store localStorage, but make sure to remove that data right after redirection or the user will keep redirecting the next time he logs into your site.

If you don't refresh the page you can pass a parameter when logging in, and as part of the login service (that I hope exists in one name or another) just redirect after you perform the login.